# EmbeddedId with foreign key

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I am trying to have Composite Primary Key with Reference to Another table.  I saw many  topics, but no answers works in my case.

In my database the columns are correctly created by foreign key for `owner_id` was not added. So I can add new record even when employee doesn't exist. 
I use `SQLLite` as database

Class a:

```
@Column(name = "filename", unique = true)
private String filename;

@EmbeddedId
private TimeSheetID id;


@MapsId("owner_id")
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "employee_id")
@ManyToOne
private EmployeeeEntity employee;
```

Class B

```
public class TimeSheetID implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7469844076039968866L;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "period")
    private String period;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "owner_id")
    private String ownerId;

    // …

}
```

Class C

```
@Column(nullable = false)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "employee_id")
public String getEmployeeID() {
    return employeeID;
}

@Column(nullable = false)
public String getBusinessUnit() {
    return businessUnit;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were quite close.

Instead of using a column name in the `@MapsId` annotation you should use the class field name which corresponds to that foreign key:

```
@MapsId("ownerId")
@ManyToOne
private EmployeeeEntity employee;
```

Also as the `@Column` is already specified in the `@Embeddable` you do not need to specify it again. There `referencedColumnName` also is not needed as your are pointing to the targets id field, which is choosen by the persistent provider by default.

Comment: Thank you for throwing some light into this matter!

Comment: How would you save (create) both the main and associated `EmployeeEntity` object?